# Scrape websites and export only the visible text to a text document Python 3 (Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

**Problem:** I am trying to scrape multiple websites using beautifulsoup for only the visible text and then export all of the data to a single text file.

This file will be used as a corpus for finding collocations using NLTK.  I'm working with something like this so far but any help would be much appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
urls = ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf"]
    for url in urls:
    website = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content)
    text = [''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('p')]
with open('thisisanew.txt','w') as file:
    for item in text:
        print(file, item)
```

Unfortunately, there are two issues with this: when I try to export the file to a .txt file it is completely blank.

Any ideas?

Comment: Times out? Could you show what is the output on timeout? And what do you mean by "export doesn't work"? any errors? Thanks.

Comment: figured out the "times out" portion and have edited the code to reflect it!  As to the part where "export doesn't work", I mean it returns a blank document!

Comment: could you also fix your indentation? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, sorry didn't see should be all set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print(file, item)` should be `print(item, file=file)`.

But don't name your files `file` as this shadows the `file` builtin, something like this is better:

```
with open('thisisanew.txt','w') as outfile:
    for item in text:
        print(item, file=outfile)
```

To solve the next problem, overwriting the data from the first URL, you can move the file writing code into your loop, and open the file once before entering the loop:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
urls = ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf"]

with open('thisisanew.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    for url in urls:
        website = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content)
        text = [''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('p')]
        for item in text:
            print(item, file=outfile)
```

Comment: Hi Mhawke, that worked half way -- it only returns the scraped data from the golf URL

Comment: That's because you overwrite `text` in your loop.

Comment: how am I able to not overwrite the loop?  Sorry I'm a bit python green

Comment: Appreciate the help but unfortunately I'm getting the same error as I did with alex when I try this code: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u02c8' in position 34: character maps to <undefined> -- any ideas.  Thank you again for your time and please provide any details so I can learn!

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, files are opened using the default encoding which I'm guessing is CP-1252 on your system (could be certain if you posted the full traceback). The unicode codepoint `'\u02c8'` has no representation in CP-1252, hence it can not be written to a file with CP-1252 encoding. Your best bet here is to use UTF-8 encoding for your file, and open the file with `open('thisisanew.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')` - see updated answer. Here's a reference to help you learn: http://www.diveintopython3.net/files.html

Comment: Thank you, especially for the reference!  Really helps to learn

Answer (score 1):

There is another problem: you are collecting the text only from the last url: reassigning the `text` variable over and over.

Define the `text` as an empty list before the loop and add new data to it inside:

```
text = []
for url in urls:
    website = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content)
    text += [''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('p')]
```

Comment: when I try this code it gives me an invalid syntax error

Comment: @user3682157 oops, sorry, check again please.

Comment: ah, just saw that it needed brackets -- thank you!  But new issue, I'm trying to combine this answer with Mhawkes but everytime I try I get the following error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u02c8' in position 34: character maps to <undefined> -- any idea why this would be (the more detail the better as I'm learning!)

Comment: @user3682157 try specifying an encoding while opening the file: `open('thisisanew.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')`.